# Can't uninstall msbuild community tasks Win10 program

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio

I'm trying to remove MSBuild Community Tasks program from my Win10 laptop but keep getting the error below when uninstalling.  I've never used it and want it gone.  Any idea how to get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: [I would use the installer from the GitHub project to uninstall it.](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks).  I would also try using [`Uninstall-Package MSBuildTasks`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/uninstall-package?view=powershell-5.1) in the [Package Manager Console.](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks)

Comment: Thanks for the response but I don't use GitHub and I never internationally installed this app. I have to wonder how good it is if it fails a simple uninstall

Comment: It was installed by somebody with access to your machine, it's not a Microsoft project, since the maintainer isn't a Microsoft employee. The **only** way it's on your machine is if somebody purposefully installed it.

Comment: Doubtfull unless it comes with another product by default.   Im the only one who uses the machine.  I keep tight control on whats installed.  Plus I don’t even have a GitHub account.

Comment: You don't need a GitHub account to download the MSI and run it.  Which is what I am suggesting you do, in order to remove it, since the uninstaller that exists on your system cannot be used (likely because it's actually missing).

Comment: I tried the latest 1.5 and 1.4.0.78 from Github and get the same error no matter if I try to install, change, modify or remove it.  Trying to install it to remove it gives me an error that it needs the 1.4.0.42 package which I can't find (1.3 is installed).  I also tried msiexec /uninstall <package> and get the same error.  The best I can tell is it came with Visual Studio. This a terrible product and I'm glad I don't rely on it.  Its installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks and there are a couple of files in the VS 8 and 10 folders.  I removed VS a long time ago.

Comment: So what about the command I suggested?  I would be shocked if Visual Studio installed it, since I have VS2022 installed, and it's not installed on my system despite all VS components being installed.

Comment: Error of a different kind.  Run from PowerShell uninstall-package 'MSbuild community tasks' and 'MSBuildTasks' both indicate the package can't be found.  I might have just clean up the registry and delete the files.  Thanks for helping.